# Reference Request: Cut locus for a Knot

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, knot-theory

If $M$ is a complete Riemannian manifold and $N$ be any submanifold of it. Then the *cut locus* of $N$ is the collection of points $q\in M$ such that minimal geodesic joining $q$ to $N$ will no longer be minimum beyond $q$. For example, in $S^2$ the cut locus of the equator is the north pole and the south pole.

**I am looking for a reference (or maybe closely related to reference):** Cut locus of a knot. Maybe trefoil knot (as it is one of the simplest ones).

Comment: Do you know anything about $M$? In particular, is it two-dimensional? Also, what do you want to know about the cut locus - definition? Measure? Complete description?

Comment: @1Rock Yeah one can assume that $M$ is two-dimensional. 

I want to know about anything related to the cut locus of the knot. The definition I have already stated, the measure is also well-studied.